# Как заменить true на false и на оборот

Tags: javascript

```
let ChangeBooleanType = {
    width: true,
    height: false,
    title: "String",
    number: 123456
};

function changeType(obj) {

    for (let key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] == "boolean") {
            
        } 
            
    }
 };

console.log(ChangeBooleanType);
```

Comment: на какой оборот?

Comment: true должно стать false, false стать true.

Comment: Встаньтe ко мне "в пол оборота", ноги на ширине плеч.

Comment: let ChangeBooleanType = {
    width: true,
    height: false,
    title: "String",
    number: 123456
};
width: false, а height: true

Comment: господа, а что реально никак не сменить true на false в чистом JS, как в React setState(ом)?
или приходится выпутываться тупа способами типа if( obj === true ) { obj = false} или я слишком глуп и не могу никак понять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А можно еще вот так извратиться)

```js
let changeBooleanType = {
  width: true,
  height: false,
  title: "String",
  number: 123456
};

let res = Object.keys(changeBooleanType).filter((key) => typeof changeBooleanType[key] === 'boolean').reduce((acc, key) => {
  return { ...acc, [key]: !acc[key] };
}, { ...changeBooleanType });

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeType(obj)
{
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] === "boolean") {
      obj[key] = !obj[key]
      console.log(key)
      console.log(obj[key])
    } 
  }
}
```

Если я правильно понял, что вам нужно дописать функцию, то вот так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `obj[key] = !obj[key]`

Comment: Согласен, так симпатичнее)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Нет, правильно писать: `if (obj[key] == true) { obj[key] = false; } else if (obj[key] == false) { obj[key] = true; }`

Comment: @Igor `if (obj[key].toString() === 'true') ...` вообще-то ;-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Во-о-от, Вы уже понимаете.

Comment: @Igor Если я еще немного помню js... `if(obj[key] === true || obj[key] === false) obj[key] != obj[key];`

Comment: Что то ни один способ не сработал(

Comment: @VladyslavTymoshenko `changeType(ChangeBooleanType);console.log(ChangeBooleanType);`

Comment: Ну я прикрепил картинку с работоспособностью... сложно сказать, что тут может не получиться))

Comment: Товарищи специалисты, я тут совсем новенький и зелёный в крапенку=)
Спасибо всем за помощь!!!